# Why are some journal articles so expensive?

Tags: publications, publishers, online-publication

Why are some journal articles so expensive, such as [this article](http://www.ingentaconnect.com/content/asp/jne/2014/00000006/00000001/art00004) that costs more than $12.55 per page to purchase?

Comment: I am not sure whether the question -in its current format- would be beneficial to the community. If you wonder about the usual cost of purchasing PDFs and whether there are limits to the cost; then please update your question.

Comment: Short answer (and this is true about a lot of things): you are paying for the intellectual content, not the raw materials. It's the same reason a DVD costs $20, even though it only costs 50¢ to manufacture.

Comment: Because the publishers can get away with it. See here: http://thecostofknowledge.com/

Comment: I guess that publishers make basically no money off single-article purchases (though I myself have resorted to buying articles online twice) and that the price point for single papers is simply to ensure that institutions buy subscriptions.

Comment: @Max: Yes, perhaps it is an incentive to do that.